# Issue in Push Notifications (APNS)

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am getting following message while sending Push Notifications from my php code:

#

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 243
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 245
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 243
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 245
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 225
>
> Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 243
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /opt/lampp/htdocs/world-vision/admin/iPhonePush/admin.php on line 245

Comment: adding what you are doing with some piece of code will make your question more understandable....

Comment: "alert certificate revoked" - have you checked that your client certificate is still valid?